# Mudar a cor de um elemento pai em uma tabela

Tags: html, css, table

estou tentando mudar a cor de um elemento pai, no meu caso quero que minha tr mude de cor caso meu input seja selecionado, porém com o css não está dando certo, alguém já se deparou com essa situação?

```css
.control:focus ~ .target {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr class="target">
     <td>
          Celula 1
      </td>
      <td>
          Celula 2
      </td>    
      <td>
       <input type="text" class="control">
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta fazer ao contrario:

```css
.target:focus-within {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr class="target">
     <td>
          <a href=''>Celula 1</a>
      </td>
      <td>
          Celula 2
      </td>    
      <td>
       <input type="text" class="control">
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

o q ele faz é setar o bgcolor na tr quando algum elemento dentro da tr esta com estado de focus

segue abaixo um exemplo um pouco mais avançado

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  line-height: 1.4;
}
body {
  padding: 20px 15%;
  background: #3c889b;
}

form {
  background: white;
}
form:focus-within {
  background: #f9f98b;
}
form header {
  padding: 2rem;
}
form header div {
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #999;
}
form header h2 {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
form > div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}
form > div:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
form > div:focus-within {
  background: #a1c084;
}
form > div > fieldset > div > div {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
form > div > label,
legend {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
form > div > div,
form > div > fieldset > div {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}
form > div > fieldset label {
  font-size: 90%;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=password],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=password] {
  width: 50%;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=url]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #4697e4;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  form > div > label,
  legend {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  form > div > div,
  form > div > fieldset > div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=url],
  input[type=password],
  textarea,
  select {
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  form > div > label,
  legend {
    text-align: right;
  }
}


Resources
```

```html
<form action="#">

  <header>
    <h2>This is a form.</h2>
    <div>This form breaks at 600px and goes from a left-label form to a top-label form. At above 1200px, the labels align right. It also indicates focused fields with :focus-within.</div>
  </header>
  
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">Full Name</label>
    <div>
      <input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">
      Email
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="email" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"> 
   </div>
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title4" for="Field4">
      Message
    </label>
  
    <div>
      <textarea id="Field4" name="Field4" spellcheck="true" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="4"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <fieldset>
    
      <legend id="title5" class="desc">
        Select a Choice
      </legend>
      
      <div>
        <input id="radioDefault_5" name="Field5" type="hidden" value="">
        <div>
          <input id="Field5_0" name="Field5" type="radio" value="First Choice" tabindex="5" checked="checked">
          <label class="choice" for="Field5_0">First Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="Field5_1" name="Field5" type="radio" value="Second Choice" tabindex="6">
          <label class="choice" for="Field5_1">Second Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="Field5_2" name="Field5" type="radio" value="Third Choice" tabindex="7">
          <label class="choice" for="Field5_2">Third Choice</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend id="title6" class="desc">
        Check All That Apply
      </legend>
      <div>
      <div>
        <input id="Field6" name="Field6" type="checkbox" value="First Choice" tabindex="8">
        <label class="choice" for="Field6">First Choice</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="Field7" name="Field7" type="checkbox" value="Second Choice" tabindex="9">
        <label class="choice" for="Field7">Second Choice</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="Field8" name="Field8" type="checkbox" value="Third Choice" tabindex="10">
        <label class="choice" for="Field8">Third Choice</label>
      </span>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title106" for="Field106">
      Select a Choice
    </label>
    <div>
    <select id="Field106" name="Field106" class="field select medium" tabindex="11"> 
      <option value="First Choice">First Choice</option>
      <option value="Second Choice">Second Choice</option>
      <option value="Third Choice">Third Choice</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div>
      <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

ex tirado de : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/

Comment: parece interessante mas... *"caso meu input seja selecionado"* e se houver outro elemento na que não seja o input, um select por exemplo, esse tbm vai ativar o seletor certo?

Comment: etao isso so vai ativar quando tiver elementos q recebam o focus. no caso se vc clicar no link nao vai aconctecer nada

Comment: esse código exemplo da pergunta é seu? https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/RZraBp

Comment: somente o primeiro cod é meu o segundo eu peguei de ex do csstricks

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente amigo, muito obrigado! :)

Comment: se copiou o código inteiro de outra pessoa deveria deixar o link com os créditos?

Comment: feito. adicionado